# Disable AlertDialog PositiveButton If No CheckBox is Checked

Tags: android, button, checkbox, android-alertdialog, builder

I've got the following code:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity.this);
builder.setTitle(R.string.str_dbox_remove_plant_title);
final HashMap<String, Integer> stuff = myCollection.getListOfStuffWithLocation();
final CharSequence[] items = stuff.keySet().toArray(new CharSequence[stuff.size()]);
final List<Integer> indexesOfSelectedStuff = new ArrayList<Integer>();
builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items, null, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked)
            indexesOfSelectedStuff.add(stuff.get(items[which].toString()));
        else if (indexesOfSelectedStuff.contains(stuff.get(items[which].toString())))
            indexesOfSelectedStuff.remove(which);
    }
});
builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.str_dbox_remove_stuff_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        for (int i = 0; i < indexesOfSelectedStuff.size(); i++) {
            myCollection.removeStuff(i);
        }
    }
});
builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.str_dbox_remove_stuff_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
    }
});              

builder.setCancelable(false); // so as to prevent the back button from closing the dialog box
final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);                  
alert.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false); // by default, disable OK button
alert.show();
```

I have an `AlertDialog` with some `CheckBox`es and I would like to disable the `PositiveButton` as long as there aren't any `CheckBox`es ticked.

I have a `List` called `indexesOfSelectedStuff` and you could say that in some way, using its `size()` method will give me an idea of how many `CheckBoxes` are selected. However, I am not sure where to place it or how to reference the `PositiveButton` within the builder. I wanted to place it on the `onClick` method (as defined in the `OnMultipleChoiceClickListener()`), like so:

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
    if (isChecked)
        indexesOfSelectedStuff.add(stuff.get(items[which].toString()));
    else if (indexesOfSelectedStuff.contains(stuff.get(items[which].toString())))
        indexesOfSelectedStuff.remove(which);
    if (indexesOfSelectedStuff.size() == 0) {
        // disable button
        // but problem is, I don't know how to reference the POSITIVE_BUTTON
    }
    else {
        // enable button
    }
}
```

I know there's a high probability that I can't insert it there. And that I'd have to do the checks after the `AlertDialog` is created. But if that is the case, what would you recommend that I use? I'm thinking of `Listener`s but which? And how should I go about it?

Comment: I know it's similar to this: [How to disable / enable dialog negative positive buttons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238952/how-to-disable-enable-dialog-negative-positive-buttons). So, the answers there somewhat suggest me to make listeners for all of my `CheckBox`es but I don't really know how many they are. Or their ids, even. 'Cause I just let the `AlertDialog.Builder` do it for me.

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to create a custom dialog. To know how check this link.
[Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011152/how-to-get-reference-to-a-button-created-in-a-custom-dialog-using-a-xml-layout)

You could try this.

Create a boolean as true.
If the check box is ticked set the Boolean value true false.

Then whenever you're creating an alert dialogue simply check if the Boolean is set to false or true. If true create a yes button else don't create a yes button. 
Now the problem is that the check button is inside alertdialog am I right if so.

Every time a check button is clicked you could close the Alert dialogue and open it again with the checkboxes already ticked ticked and with no yes button. That is use the referenced button to set disabled. Or in technical terms  `setEnabled = "false;"`

Of course this is laggy etc but this is all I can do. Sorry

Comment: Link's not working. Anyway, thank you for your suggestion. I will be considering it if I can't find any other way. :)

Comment: I am extremely sorry. Please check the link now.

Comment: LOL. Buddy, it's okay. Stop saying, "Sorry". You make me sound like I'm mean. Again, thanks.

Comment: No problem. Just saying.